# Full-height sidenav under a toolbar (cross-device)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I set my sidenav to fit 100% of the screen height this way:

**My app.component.html:**

```
<md-toolbar>etc</md-tooblar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

One of my routes refers to the sidenav this way:

**admin.component.ts**

```
<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true" class="sidenav">
        My Sidenav
  </md-sidenav>

  <div class="sidenav-content mat-typography">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

admin.component.css:

```
md-sidenav-container {
   height: 100vh;
}
```

The problem is that the height is 100% not including the toolbar from my main app component, and there is a scrollbar in any of my pages.

I tried to set my md-sidenav-container height to 93% (which fits perfectly in my screen) but in other screens the container misses about 30-50 pixels from the bottom of the screen (the container don't reach the screen bottom).

Any solution for this?

Comment: `height: 100%` is relative to the parent `div`'s height. Wouldn't `height: 100vh` be more appropriate here?

Comment: how about 100vh instead of 100%.  On the other hand why do you have <router-outlet> twice?

Comment: I tried to `height: 100vh`, the result is same: scrollbar appears in every single page (the toolbar height is not calculated). I have 2 `<router-outlest> `because those are 2 different modules.

Comment: Then put calc(100vh) - heightOfToolbar

Comment: @Vega Nice one! `height: calc(100vh - 50px);` did the trick, now the height works great on any screen

Comment: The scrollbar appears because of white space margin. try adding `vertical-align: middle;` alongside the `height: 100vh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting

```
md-sidenav-container {
   height: calc(100vh - hightOfToolbar);
}
```

should work on everywhere as you will adjust the container height to screen max height - toolbar's height.